# send HTML markup from Custom Field to the Email Campaign

Tags: php, html, email, infusionsoft

I have an E-commerce website and is integrated to [InfusionSoft](http://infusionsoft.com)

What currently happening is that...

Customer completes an order on my website and purchases, let say 2 products.

Upon Order Completion, Order Received tag is added and customer's info is added to InfusionSoft, and the **Order Detail HTML Markup (which is generated on my website via code) is added to a Custom Field, `~_myCustomField~`**

There is already a campaign running which send simple Thank You Email to customer.

What I want is that I can send the Order Detail(which is stored in `~_myCustomField~`) along with the Thank You Email

What I have tried that, **I have added the custom field into *Campaign's Email* just like `~Contact._myCustomField~` but *it sends the only HTML, not generated one!***

`_myCustomField` contains for example

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>This is your order detail</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving the HTML into a custom field, you can just send the thank you email at that point.

You can use the email service to send an email:
https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/read/Email_Service

example:

```
$title = "template API test";
$category = "API Category";
$fromAddress = "from@infusionsoft.com";
$toAddress = "~Contact.Email~";
$ccAddress = "";
$bccAddresses = "";
$subject = "My Fancy Subject Line";
$textBody = "This is the text email body";
$htmlBody = "HTML"
$contentType = "Contact";
$mergeContext = "";
$tmpId = $app->addEmailTemplate($title, $category, $fromAddress, $toAddress, $ccAddress, $bccAddresses, $subject, $textBody, $htmlBody, $contentType, $mergeContext);
```

If you want to keep the interaction with the campaign, you can use the goal feature. Learn more about [goals here](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/blog/read/Campaign_Builder_for_Developers_By_a_Developer).

You will be after the [funnel service](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/read/Funnel_Service#achieveGoal) to see if a goal has been completed (such as an order) and send the Thank you email at that point.

Comment: I created a template i IS
imported into my code.
And split from a specific point
Added my own content.
Merged it.
And sent the Email using iSDK function using PHP.